# Visual Studio doesn't respond to "back" key

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Probably a stupid question:

I have a button on my mouse for navigating "back" (used in web browsers, file explorer, Visual Studio, etc). Recently, the button stopped working in Visual Studio (it still works elsewhere). Clicking the "back" button in the top-right of VS still works, it's just the button on my mouse somehow got "disconnected" (but only in the case of VS). Is there a Visual Studio setting I can change to get this to work again?

Visual Studio 2015 v14.0.25425.01 Update 3 btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try launching Visual Studio both as Administrator and regularly.  I've noticed difficulty in debugging file drag/drop to win forms on Windows 10 as Administrator, so it may correlate to the VS mouse environment even when not debugging.

Comment: That was it! Quite annoying.